# Why does facebook app role id differ from user id?

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, facebook-graph-api

I have a nodeJS application with facebook login provided by facebook-passport strategy. Once user logins, I save his data to my own database for later use. For this I have needed to create a facebook app. From the facebook app's configurations I have set up people for roles. In my application (server side), I plan to query these role people, and allow login only if a person is listed for a role. I used the facebook Graph API to query myself from the roles (this required first getting an app access token). I managed to query myself, and get my own user id. But this was little different than the id stored in my app's database. Everything was exactly the same except the last two numbers in the id. In my database, the last two were 40, and in the graph api query the last two were 39. How come they differ?

I do know that the user ids are app-scoped, so that each app has its own id for a user. But since I did put myself as a role for the app, it should return me the same app-scoped id, right? Or could the app-scoped ids change when the facebook app is updated? I have updated it quite many times, so I wonder if that could be the case. Or then something related to my own database. I used mongoose (mongoDB), and the schema type for the id is Number.

Comment: Sounds like you might have stored user ids as integers. Since they easily flow outside of the range of valid integers, they might get treated as floats instead, and that would explain the difference. __Always__ store (and in general, treat) Facebook (user) ids as string values.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot :). Put your comment as an answer, and I will select it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might have stored user ids as integers. Since they easily flow outside of the range of valid integers, they might get treated as floats instead, and that would explain the difference.

**Always** store (and in general, treat) Facebook (user) ids as string values.